# Efficient way to reduce memory (RAM) consumption while writing huge file data into XML

Tags: java, xml, serialization, marshalling, stax

I have to write 7 list into XML file, and each list would be of size 1 GB to 5 GB.

Expected out XML file is as follows:

```
<doc>
    <items1>
        <itemA>..</itemA>
        ..
    </items1>

    <items2>
        <itemB>..</itemB>
        ..
    </items2>

    <items3>
        <itemC>..</itemC>
        ..
    </items3>
    .
    .
    .
    <items7>
        <itemG>..</itemG>
        ..
    </items7>
</doc>
```

Java objects are like:

```
List<ItemA> items1 = new List<>(); // 1GB-5GB
List<ItemB> items2 = new List<>(); // 1GB-5GB
List<ItemC> items3 = new List<>(); // 1GB-5GB
List<ItemD> items4 = new List<>(); // 1GB-5GB
List<ItemE> items5 = new List<>(); // 1GB-5GB
List<ItemF> items6 = new List<>(); // 1GB-5GB
List<ItemG> items7 = new List<>(); // 1GB-5GB
```

Wrapping all list into a single object(catalogue) into a Java object, and marshalling in one go consumes lots of memory, also every time when this list size increases we have to scale our infra. Below is the code:

```
JAXBContext.newInstance("ta").createMarshaller().marshal(new ObjectFactory().createCatalogue(catalogue), new FileOutputStream(fileName));
```

Here catalogue is a Java object containing all the seven list.

Is there any smart way where can I reduce memory consumption, by writing data in chunks. I explored [stax](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/xml/stax.html) for this, but I was not able to find method to write list of data.

Is there any way in Java to write up to 20 GB in an efficient manner into XML, without scaling RAM over infra?

We want to write each list separately, also previously written file should not be load into heap while writing next list.

Comment: In the first place, there is no reason for you to keep such huge lists on your RAM. The contents of these lists are created by code or by reading from another file?

Comment: we  can break this part, you can assume we are reading this list from db directly, we want to write each list in chunk, not all the list in one go.

Comment: So basically you want an efficient way to divide this data into chunks in order to write them into XML?

Comment: I ask again, as in your [recently deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69602650/207421). How do you know it's a *leak?* Rather than just running out of memory? It isn't the same thing. And "it is very obvious all the java object are in memory until marshalled into xml" wasn't an answer, and isn't now.

Comment: @user207421
 Its not leak, I was wrong, memory consumption is high, objects only got GC when entire file created, we want it to breakdown so after each list write object should be available to GC, also previously written file should not be load into heap while writing next list.

Comment: @user207421 I also don't think it's a memory leak. Maybe he is just a little confused by the difference between the concepts.

Comment: @TheCurious I will propose as an answer a chunking method.

Comment: So fix the title and the content of your question.

Comment: @InSaNiTy I'm not interested in 'maybe'. It's up to the OP to clarify. Not up to us to guess what he means.

Comment: I dont know why there is confusion. I have used term memory leak which means unused object is not available to GC,was incorrect, I have updated the same. Problem statement is that every time when this list size increases we have to scale our infra.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using StAX is most likely the best way, not only because you don't have to keep the whole XML document in memory, but because you also don't have to keep all *items* in memory. Don't know where you looked for writing with StAX but I found the following in [The Java EE 5 Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbem.html#bnbfe):

> The following example, taken from the StAX specification, shows how to
> instantiate an output factory, create a writer, and write XML output:
>
> ```java
> XMLOutputFactory output = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
> XMLStreamWriter writer = output.createXMLStreamWriter( ... );
> writer.writeStartDocument(); 
> writer.setPrefix("c","http://c");
> writer.setDefaultNamespace("http://c");
> writer.writeStartElement("http://c","a");
> writer.writeAttribute("b","blah");
> writer.writeNamespace("c","http://c");
> writer.writeDefaultNamespace("http://c");
> writer.setPrefix("d","http://c");
> writer.writeEmptyElement("http://c","d");
> writer.writeAttribute("http://c","chris","fry");
> writer.writeNamespace("d","http://c"); 
> writer.writeCharacters("Jean Arp"); 
> writer.writeEndElement(); 
> writer.flush();
> ```
>
> This code generates the following XML (new lines are non-normative):
>
> ```xml
> <?xml version=’1.0’ encoding=’utf-8’?> 
> <a b="blah" xmlns:c="http://c" xmlns="http://c">
>   <d:d d:chris="fry" xmlns:d="http://c"/>
>   Jean Arp
> </a>
> ```

**Edit:** I also notice that there's a section on [generating XML with StAX in the link you posted](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/xml/stax.html#1104639). Also, note that there's nothing special about "writing a list", you just iterate over the list and write one tag per entry. Something like this:

```java
XMLStreamWriter writer = ...;
writer.writeStartDocument();
writer.writeStartElement("doc");

// Write the first list:
writer.writeStartElement("items1");
for (ItemA e: items1) {
  writer.writeStartElement("itemA");
  // TODO: Write attributes, sub-elements, text or whatever is needed
  writer.writeEndElement();
});
writer.writeEndElement();

// TODO: Write items2, items3, ..., items7 in the same fashion as items1

// Close document
writer.writeEndElement();
writer.writeEndDocument();
```

The XMLStreamWriter is low-level, which means that it doesn't do much more for you other than write XML to a stream, but it's not complicated. So you may end up with quite a few more lines of code than when using JAXB, but the code you have to write won't be particularly hard to write.

Comment: The Faster-XML team recommends Woodstox over Stax.

Comment: @gustafc Let's say I have to write same list in items1 & items4, Is there any way we can write same data in two differeent element without closing one element.

Comment: @DwB I can imagine, since they wrote it. Nevertheless, Woodstox is a StAX implementation so recommendation for StAX still stands :)

Comment: @TheCurious Not really sure what you're after, but spontaneously I'd say "no". StAX just writes XML as a stream, you can't jump back & forth. Perhaps you'd like to post a new question here with more details on what you envision.